# Python: transform milliseconds to datetime object

Tags: python, mongodb

does anyone has an idea on how to transform milliseconds to a datetime object?
Here is my request:

```
ts = 1538589841191
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.local
collection = db.orderbook_update
orderbook = collection.find_one({
    "lastUpdated": ts
})
```

and my result of `orderbook[u'lastUpdated']` = 1538589841191.0

Does someone have an idea on how to transform this float into a datetime object to end up with something like: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3, 16, 27, 29, 198000)

Comment: Do you need a solution using pandas or mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
from datetime import datetime
ms = 1538589841191.0
obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000)  ## fromtimestamp accepts arguments in seconds
```